# JDBC Query output returned via mapPartitions

Tags: apache-spark

Whilst this example is easy to follow:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 3)
def myfunc(index: Int, iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[String] = {
    iter.map(x => index + "," + (x, x, x+100))
}
rdd1.mapPartitionsWithIndex(myfunc).collect()
```

I have been experimenting to get some data via JDBC calls inside mapPartitions with the idea of allowing some rudimentary parallel processing. In fact the example I present is not actually valid, but for arguments sake, imagine there is some JDBC source with let us say, some complicated logic, that does not fit dataframes, easy RDD processing, etc. Please bear with me.

So, I have simulated some calls, but as opposed to the example above, I am not sure how to return the Any return parameter from the database. That is my question.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.util.Properties

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("G%", "C%", "I%", "B%", "X%", "F%", "J%"), 3)

def myfunc(index: Int, iter: Iterator[String]) : Iterator[Any] = {

    val jdbcHostname = "mysql-rfam-public.ebi.ac.uk"
    val jdbcPort = 4497
    val jdbcDatabase = "Rfam"
    val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}"
    val jdbcUsername = "rfamro"
    val jdbcPassword = ""
    val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
    connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)

    iter.map { x => val val1 = x; 
                val statement = connection.createStatement()
                val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s"""(select DISTINCT type from family where type like '${val1}' ) """)
                while ( resultSet.next() ) {
                        val hInType = resultSet.getString("type")
                } 
             }
}

rdd1.mapPartitionsWithIndex(myfunc).collect()
```

I get empty data, I get that, but I am not sure if what I want is possible or how to amend the approach. I am thinking of the preserve partition point for example.

The approach below is of course fine, but easy to follow - even for me!

```
    iter.map(x => index + "," + (x, x, x+100))
```

So, I tried this but always get null output. I think what I may be trying cannot work. I get the impression the compiler thinks it can go straight to last statement. True? I am also assuming that the connection is only done once per Partition - not sure now.

```
...
var fruits = new ListBuffer[String]()

iter.map { x => val val1 = x; 
                println (x)
                val statement = connection.createStatement()
                val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s"""(select DISTINCT type from family where type like '${val1}' ) """)
                while ( resultSet.next() ) {
                        val hInType = resultSet.getString("type")
                        fruits += hInType

                } 
          }

return fruits.toList.toIterator
```

Comment: Have tried  few options, but left the code uncluttered for simplicity

Comment: May be this is not possible...

Comment: My conclusion is that this does not fit the SPARK Paradigms and that I would need to use foreachPartition and  write to  a temp table etc.

Comment: I wrote a function and that seems to be the way to go, ReadMatchFromDB as people point out on other threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but a totally different approach, not sure the above can ever

```
import java.util.Properties
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import java.sql.{Connection, Driver, DriverManager, JDBCType, PreparedStatement, ResultSet, ResultSetMetaData, SQLException}

def readMatchingFromDB(record: String, connection: Connection) : String = {

    var hInType: String = "XXX"
    val val1 = record 
    val statement = connection.createStatement()
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s"""(select MAX(type) as type from family where type like '${val1}' ) """) // when doing MAX must do as so next line works

    while ( resultSet.next() ) {
            hInType = resultSet.getString("type")                       
        }   
    return hInType // Only returning 1 due to MAX
 }

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("G%", "C%", "I%", "B%", "X%", "F%", "J%"), 3)
val newRdd = rdd1.mapPartitions(

      partition => {
         val jdbcHostname = "mysql-rfam-public.ebi.ac.uk"
         val jdbcPort = 4497
         val jdbcDatabase = "Rfam"
         val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}"
         val jdbcUsername = "rfamro"
         val jdbcPassword = ""
         val connectionProperties = new Properties()
         connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
         connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
         val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)

         val newPartition = partition.map(
           record => {  
                      readMatchingFromDB(record, connection)
                     }).toList

         connection.close()
         newPartition.toIterator  
     }).collect
```

Comment: Actual implementation as opposed to placeholders

Comment: Partition preservation is an interesting point. Also , this is a contrived example - but for which I am using for a more realistic use case.

Comment: Actually no reason for the question now, but it may help others